# Retrieve and process JSON pages on Windows

Tags: json, windows, batch-file, wsh

On Windows I need to retrieve the contents of multiple JSON pages like [this](http://stats.grok.se/json/en/200910/Wikipedia:WikiProject%20Video%20games/Traffic%20statistics) and append them to one large text file. What would be the easiest way to do this? I don't have a lot of programming experience, but I can use batch files and JScript/Windows Scripting Host. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wget` or `curl` are great command line tools for pulling down a web page and saving to file from a command line script.  Either one will likely work for you. Google for either.

To append one file onto another from the command line or batch file, you can do something like this:

```
copy FILE1+FILE2 FILE3
```

That will append the contents of FILE1 and FILE2 together and save it as FILE3.  You can chain more than two files too. E.g. `copy A.txt+B.txt+C.txt D.txt`

You could likely combine wget/curl with the copy command and have a reasonable BAT file to accomplish what you describe.

Comment: How many files can I append using that command? I have dozens. Is there enough space in the command line?